# Is the conjunction "while" sub-ordinate or co-ordinate?

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

I ran into a sentence.

> We're living at my parents' house **while** we look for a new home.

In the sentence, is the conjunction "while" sub-ordinate or co-ordinate?
Please explain it to me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "while" is a subordinate conjunction. http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000377.htm

Answer (score 1):

**While** is a **subordinate conjunction** linking the independent clause

> We're living at my parents' house

with the dependent clause

> we look for a new home

Both subordinate and coordinate conjunctions can be listed and the lists are mutually exclusive [**here**](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-conjunctions.html)

Comment: It's a great site, reviving the lost art of sentence diagramming, which  appeals to the engineer in me.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional grammar, *while* is a **subordinating** conjunction: the clause which it introduces is called a **subordinate clause**

Traditional grammar bases this classification on the sort of complement which the word takes in a specific context: words are classified as subordinating conjunctions only when they introduce a clause. However, these "conjunctions" do not behave much like coordinating conjunctions; they behave more like prepositions, and in fact are classifed by traditional grammar as prepositions when they take non-clause complements.

Consequently, many modern grammarians reject the traditional classification and regard almost all of traditional grammar's subordinating conjunctions, including *while*, as **prepositions**. This is the position of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, which recognizes only three 'true' subordinators: *whether*, *if* when it is used with the same sense as *whether*, and *that*.